# MaterialTimePicker does not allow user to pick seconds

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am working on a flutter project where it is required by the user that the user must have to pick the time in `hours:minutes:seconds`, by using `showTimePicker()` I am able to pick the hours and minutes but i cannot find any way to pick the seconds. any help in this regard will be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [pub package link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_time_picker_spinner)
2. [source code](https://github.com/icemanbsi/flutter_time_picker_spinner)

flutter_time_picker_spinner provides functionality to select/pick seconds, one can observe it's source code or use this third party package as per requirement. Read the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_time_picker_spinner/latest/) to know more or get look on [source code](https://github.com/icemanbsi/flutter_time_picker_spinner) and modify the provided MaterialTimePicker.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
                //put some interesting code
            }
        },
        now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
        now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
        true
    );
    tpd.setMinTime(10, 0, 0); // MIN: hours, minute, secconds
    tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePickerDialog");
```

The easiest way to add the `Material DateTime Picker` library to your project is by adding it as a dependency to your `build.gradle`.

Comment: This one is for android, I am working on flutter by the way thanks for help